# Should RESTful JSON endpoints end in .js? What about JSONP?

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, rest

We're building out a RESTful API, which mainly returns JSON formatted responses. Most resources also will conditionally wrap the response in a JSONP formatted based on whether or not the query param, "callback" is present.

My question is, "Should we be ending the names of our endpoints with '.js', since they're JSON?"

Typically webservices don't end with file extensions. However, if we're thinking of URLs as static resources (by dynamically generated) and not services, then it makes sense to me to give the endpoints file extensions.

Would doing this change anything? Is it beneficial or harmful in any way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. They should not have a `.js` extension which indicates JavaScript. JavaScript is an ECMAScript implementation while JSON is a markup *based on* ECMAScript object literal syntax - but *JavaScript is not JSON*. If you *do* need file extensions (which I would suggest omitting if possible), at least use `.json`.

Comment: Good point. I have come across issues where .js was needed vs .json (IIS configuration within a tightly controlled corporate environment), but that wouldn't be the norm. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: it might help caching if you proved an extenstion and no queryString, but you might not want caching anyway, in which case the answer is a strong NO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably largely a matter of personal taste, but I would not recommend it, especially if you have a public facing API.

For some reason, if I see a file extension that isn't a well known dynamically generated content (like `.php`, `.jsp`, `.cgi` or the like), I tend to assume it's a static file, so I might wrongly assume I can cache it or treat it like it's static content.  A good set of documentation might clear things up, but giving it a `.js` extension might just make things confusing for other developers.

Also, @user2864740 left a good comment about standards and other things.  I wish I knew more about those to tack on to the end of this answer, so read up on his contributions.